# Ĉu ekzistas registro de Esperantaj idiomoj?

Tags: idiom, language

Mi volas scii, ĉar mi min demandas ĉu oni povas diri "varma" por amor-instiga ino/ulo? Kiel oni diras *trap* en esperanto? Ĉu tiuj estas nur-anglaj idiomoj?

Comment: Ne ĉiu vorto havas ekzaktan tradukon en ĉiu lingvo. Feliĉe mi kredas ke la tre aĉa vorto “trap” estas (kaj espereble restos) nur de anglalingva kulturo. Mi kredas ke via registro de “idiomoj” estus fakte simple nomata “vortaro”.

Comment: Mi ne povis trovi la kroman signifon de "trap" en la reto, eĉ en Vikivortaro. Kompreneble estas idiotismoj en ĉiuj lingvoj sed nur tre malmultaj en esperanto, vidu ekzemple: https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantaj_idiotismoj

Comment: @DominikCornice https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/trap

Comment: Ampleksa kaj plena registro de Esperantaj idiomoj verŝajne ne ekzistas, kaj multaj Esperantaj idiomoj nun estas efektive raraj (ekz. ĵuri aŭ blasfemi "je la bardo/je la barbo de..."; nomi iun "samideano"). Aldone, ni evitu fremdigaj kaj afliktaj vortoj kiel "trap".

Answer (score 1):

Por respondi al "Ĉu ekzistas registro de Esperantaj idiomoj?":

Tatoeba estas registro de ekzemplaj frazoj kaj tradukoj, alŝutita de uzantoj: https://tatoeba.org/

Sed, kelkfoje estas multaj malsimilaj ekzemploj pri unu vorto. Mi ofte esploras la detalaj definoj de la ekzemploj en ie alia, post mi trovas ilin, por trovi la plej bonan por mia dezirata signifo.

Ekzemple, pri "hot": https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=hot&from=eng&to=epo

Ni trovas:

> "She's hot -> ŝi estas ekscita" (She is exciting)
>   "Tom is hot -> Tom estas seksalloga" (Tom is sex-appealing)
>   (ktp.)